# performance of Replace vs If exists update else insert vs update if row_count()=0 insert

Tags: mysql, update, insert, replace

Structure of my table is:

```
Id           int(11)        NO     PRI      auto_increment
Mobile       varchar(10)    NO          
LoanAmount   int(11)        NO
```

I want to UPDATE if existing Mobile else INSERT new entry.

What have I tried?

- Using REPLACE as there is no foreign key constrain
- `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE Mobile='SomeValue')
  UPDATE ... 
  WHERE Mobile=v_mobile
  ELSE
  INSERT INTO table ...`
- `UPDATE table SET (...) WHERE Mobile='SomeValue' 
  IF ROW_COUNT()=0 
  INSERT INTO table.person (...) VALUES (...)`

Which would be best in terms of performance or future maintenance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Usually* the answer is simply "which one sends more requests to the server".

- IODKU - 1
- REPLACE - 1
- EXISTS - 2 (SELECT, plus either UPDATE or INSERT)
- ROW_COUNT - 1 or 2 (ROW_COUNT does not count)

But we have a tie with that metric.  So, let's dissect the winners:

- IODKU - Find the row, decide what do, then do it.
- REPLACE - DELETE all rows that match on any UNIQUE (or PRIMARY) KEY, then INSERT.

It feels like IODKU will be less work.

Comment: As you can see in the table, Id is the primary key. I want to replace duplicate of Mobile. Would that be possible using IODKU?

Comment: You need `UNIQUE(mobile)` for `REPLACE` to work.  And for IODKU to work.  Furthermore, your `SELECT` and `UPDATE` will be _slow_ table scans without some kind of index.  That is, your code will be twice as slow.